# SharePoint 2013: Check Workflow status programmatically (javascript)?

Tags: 2013, workflow, javascript

I need to be able to get the status of a SharePoint workflow 2013 using javascript.

My goal is to start in a loop for all selected items synchronously a workflow. For that I will check if the started Workflow is completed before I start the next one.

```
/* Run workflows for multiple list items */
function StartWorkflowForSelectedItems() {
    showInProgressDialog();
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var subID = '{BE3F6F70-E1E3-4105-8351-0DFB246EA451}';
    var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());
    var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);
    ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            var params = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
                var itemId = selectedItems[i].id;
                var test = wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemId, params);

               // wait until Workflow is Complete
            }
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function (sender, args) {
                closeInProgressDialog();
                reloadWindow()

            },
            function (sender, args) {
            closeInProgressDialog();
            alert('Failed to run workflow');
            }
        );
},
function (sender, args) {
    closeInProgressDialog();
    alert('Failed to run workflow');
}
   );
}
```

Does anyone have any ideas or code around this?

//Edit

Thanks for your answer, but when I include your solution in my code shown below I get an exception:

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been
>   requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be
>   explicitly requested.

for  var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value

What I´m doing wrong?

```
/* Run workflows for multiple list items */
function StartWorkflowForSelectedItems() {

    showInProgressDialog();
    var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems();
    var subID = '{5A407502-2F30-41AE-A43E-0FA62CC4F7C3}';
    var wfManager = SP.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager.newObject(ctx, ctx.get_web());
    var subscription = wfManager.getWorkflowSubscriptionService().getSubscription(subID);

    for (var i = 0; i < selectedItems.length; i++) {
        var itemId = selectedItems[i].id;


    ctx.load(subscription, 'PropertyDefinitions');
    ctx.executeQueryAsync(
        function (sender, args) {
            var params = {};

            wfManager.getWorkflowInstanceService().startWorkflowOnListItem(subscription, itemId, params);

                // wait until Workflow is Complete

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(
                function (sender, args) {
                    closeInProgressDialog();
                    reloadWindow()

                },
                function (sender, args) {
                    closeInProgressDialog();
                    alert('Failed to run workflow');
                }
            );
        },
function (sender, args) {
    closeInProgressDialog();
    alert('Failed to run workflow');
}
   );



    //Example: check whether workflow has been completed for a List Item
    var listTitle = 'Agendapunkte';
    var listItemId = itemId;
    var workflowTitle = 'verschieben von Agendapunkte nach AgendaProtokoll und Meeting';
    getWorkflowStatus(listTitle, listItemId, workflowTitle, function (status) {
        if (status == 5) {
            console.log('Approval is completed');
        }
    },
        function (sender, args) {
             console.log(args.get_message());
        });
    }
}


function getWorkflowStatus(listTitle, listItemId, workflowTitle, success, error) {
    var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
    var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);
    context.load(listItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(
       function () {
           var workflowStatusField = listItem.get_parentList().get_fields().getByTitle(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field
           var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value
           success(workflowStatusValue);
       },
       function () { alert("error")}
    );
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### How to get Workflow status via CSOM

```
function getWorkflowStatus(listTitle,listItemId,workflowTitle, success,error)
{
  var context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
  var web = context.get_web();
  var list = web.get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
  var listItem = list.getItemById(listItemId);   
  context.load(listItem);
  context.executeQueryAsync(
     function() {
       var workflowStatusField = listItem.get_parentList().get_fields().getByTitle(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field
       var workflowStatusValue = listItem.get_item(workflowTitle); //get workflow status field value
       success(workflowStatusValue); 
     },
     error
  );
}



//Example: check whether workflow has been completed for a List Item
var listTitle = 'Pages';
var listItemId = 1;
var workflowTitle = 'Approval';
getWorkflowStatus(listTitle,listItemId,workflowTitle,function(status){
   if(status == 5){  
       console.log('Approval is completed');
   } 
},
function(sender,args){
   console.log(args.get_message());
});
```